# Rails link_to link fills out form on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4.0
Ruby 2.0

I am trying to create a link that fills out a textarea field on the current page with data that I already have.

Here is my code for the view (that doesn't work)

```
<% if feed_item.in_reply_to %>
<%= link_to "reply", mentions_path(:content => "@#{feed_item.user.username}") %>
<% end %>
```

All I want is `@#{feed_item.user.username}` to be entered into a textarea called `micropost_content`

Any help or something that'll point me in the right direction would be great

--C

***EDIT:***

Everyone seems to be confused with the @...I'm putting the @ because I want it to display on the page as

@usernmae

Since the username is stored as `username` in the DB.

It's not because I'm trying to insert an "instance variable" :-)

Can't this be done with Javascript?

This better explains it:

[image]

Comment: I think you dont need that @ sign appended when you do string manipulation in ruby. all you have to do us mentions_path(:content => "#{feed_item.user.username}") . let me know if this works i'll post it as an answer

Comment: can you check if the link actually resolves the username ? may be its being resolved to null or something like that

Comment: It does resolve the username...I have the debug on. Can this be done as javascript?

Comment: Cool then you should be able to catch it as params[:content] on your mention page. Can you try printing params[:content] on your mention page?

Comment: Thanks for your time so far. I added an update to better illustrate what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to do and check (just in case):

- check that `mentions_path` is routing to the correct controller and action, where you want the form
- remove the `@` from the evaluated string and check the `params[:content]` value in the controller, it should contain the correct username
- if you are using a `form_for` helper in the view

  - then assign that content to the appropriate field of the model, that you are building the form for
- else

  - assign that content to an instance variable like `@username` and then use `text_area_tag :field_name, @username`

Ok, if you need that on the same page just do something like

```
$(document).ready -> 
  $("#reply_link_id").click ->
    username = $('#username_link_id').html()
    $('#textarea_id').val(username).focus()
    return false
```

Comment: Thanks for your time so far. I added an update to better illustrate what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

I got the behavior I was looking for by doing this

```
<%= link_to "reply", '#', :onclick => "document.getElementById('micropost_content').value='@#{feed_item.user.username} ';return false;" %>
```

Although now I am looking for a way to put the cursor there

Comment: look a bit higher - added the focus() to my answer

Answer (score 0):

on the new page you can check if the value that you are passing exist and added to the value of the field that you want populated